# How to access legendSymbols and change their shape in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with markers disabled.
The legendSymbol is currently a line. I would like to show the symbol as a square. Any pointers?

Comment: I found posts suggesting the use :$(chart.series).each(function(){
    this.legendSymbol.attr('height',8);... However this does not work for me. this does not seem to contain legendSymbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two series (one normal and one fake) with defined custom symbol. First should be hidden in legend. Then only what you need is use `legendItemClick` and call action.

http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/339/

Comment: If you use the `linkedTo` option, then you don't need to mess with the click event.  Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/340/

Comment: I found this solution working well for me. However, I decided to calculate the legend position and draw rectangles using renderer instead.

Comment: Your fiddle seems broken.

Answer (score 6):

With the latest Highcharts release you can also exchange the method that draws the legend icon from outside of Highcharts:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.line.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = 
     Highcharts.seriesTypes.area.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
```

To use the element that is drawn for the area chart as an icon for a line graph. 
(I have used this in Highcharts Stockcharts but this should be applicable in basic Highcharts as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `stroke-width` attribute on the path element.

We can provide functions to Highcharts that will be drawn whenever the chart is drawn.  Since `redraw` is not called on the first drawing the `load` event is needed

```
  chart: {

      events: {
          load: function () { 
              $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
          },
          redraw: function () {
              $(".highcharts-legend-item path").attr('stroke-width', 10);
          }
      }
  },
```

I like this as it's quicker than than the other two answers and adding a "fake series" feels like a hack.

If you need further customization Hendrik's would be great!  The original question asked for a square, if all that's really needed is a rectangle (or a large square) this works great.

Also Hendrik's answer didn't work for me out of the box in High**Stocks**, this does.