# Pie Chart Solid gaugue

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

1) I am using `pie chart` to display chart and type is "solid gauge". May i know how to change color of legend symbol?

2) I am using `line chart` to display chart values and type is "line" and need to set legend type as square and by default is "LINE"

Please help me in this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: 1) Set `series.color` or `series.data[index].color`. I am not sure which one, because "pie chart" is not the same as "solid gauge". 2) Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812476/how-to-access-legendsymbols-and-change-their-shape-in-highcharts).