# Highcharts use legend symbol and legend parms, not scatter marker symbols - in scatter plot

Tags: highcharts

I have built multiple bar charts using the same legend setup but it does not seem to transfer to a scatter plot.  It instead uses the scatter marker symbols inside the legend.

I need the marker symbols to be circle and the legend symbols to be square but without using a custom legend but can't seem to get there

These are the legend options for bar graphs I am using. It works as intended but when added to the scatter plot, the legend symbol options are not being honored while the `itemStyle`, `cursor`, `align` and `verticalAlign` are...but the legend symbols are coming from the scatter marker symbols and seem to be linked.

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    symbolRadius: 0,
    symbolHeight: 16,
    symbolPadding: 15,
    itemMarginBottom: 20,
    itemStyle: {
        fontFamily: chartFont,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize
    },
    cursor: 'pointer',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top'
}
```

The marker symbol options are defined in the series array as:

```
marker: {
    enabled: true, symbol: 'circle', radius: 15
}
```

Comment: I think that a bug, you should summit this issue on the [Github repo](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues)

Comment: @Core972 why do you think this is a bug? This is the expected behavior - the chart will use a symbol appropriate to the series and/or marker type. I am not aware of configuration options to change the symbol in the legend, though there may well be a workaround...

Comment: See if this topic helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812476/how-to-access-legendsymbols-and-change-their-shape-in-highcharts

Comment: Try a scatter chart with [this](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.squareSymbol) .

Comment: @Core972  gave `squareSymbol` a shot, but no luck, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheieve the wanted result, you can use the way of drawing legend symbol from `column` series and set `symbolRadius` to `0`:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.scatter.prototype.drawLegendSymbol =
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],
    legend: {
        symbolRadius: 0
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4epgLos0/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: in the snippet I provided, I already have `symbolRadius` set to 0.

Comment: Hi james, Yes, but you did not overwrite the method in `scatter` prototype. Please check the live demo above.